# Eclipse Android Application Crash

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, crash, supportmapfragment

I am building a GPS application using Google Maps v2 API. The activity has SupportMapFragment and some text strings. When I run the application on my Android smartphone, it crashes. I dont understand the LogCat. Source code below.

Paramedic.java

```
package ie.itsligo.medication;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class Paramedic extends FragmentActivity {

    TextView txtID;
    TextView txtFName;
    TextView txtLName;
    TextView txtMedInfo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_paramedic);

        txtID = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtID);
        txtFName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtFName);
        txtLName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtLName);
        txtMedInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtMedInfo);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.paramedic, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

activity_paramedic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Patient Location"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="231dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Patient Details"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Patient ID:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtFName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="First Name:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Last Name:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtMedInfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Medical Information:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="ie.itsligo.medication"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <permission android:name="ie.itsligo.medication.permission.MAPS_RECIEVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="ie.itsligo.medication.permission.MAPS_RECIEVE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

        <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true"/>

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name=".Paramedic"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value=""/>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

LogCat

```
02-15 13:12:30.549: D/dalvikvm(31488): GC_CONCURRENT freed 120K, 10% free 10493K/11655K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 31ms
02-15 13:12:30.549: D/dalvikvm(31488): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 8ms
02-15 13:12:30.909: D/dalvikvm(31488): GC_CONCURRENT freed 136K, 11% free 10821K/12039K, paused 6ms+255ms, total 291ms
02-15 13:12:30.979: I/Google Maps Android API(31488): Google Play services client version: 6587000
02-15 13:12:30.989: I/Google Maps Android API(31488): Google Play services package version: 6599034
02-15 13:12:31.299: D/dalvikvm(31488): GC_CONCURRENT freed 324K, 11% free 11375K/12743K, paused 13ms+3ms, total 53ms
02-15 13:12:31.299: D/dalvikvm(31488): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 16ms
02-15 13:12:31.429: D/dalvikvm(31488): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 966K, 15% free 11888K/13959K, paused 38ms, total 38ms
02-15 13:12:32.090: D/dalvikvm(31488): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1123K, 15% free 13363K/15559K, paused 3ms+28ms, total 146ms
02-15 13:12:32.090: D/dalvikvm(31488): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 81ms
02-15 13:12:32.661: D/dalvikvm(31488): GC_CONCURRENT freed 691K, 11% free 14087K/15815K, paused 13ms+10ms, total 131ms
02-15 13:12:32.661: D/dalvikvm(31488): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 39ms
02-15 13:12:33.131: W/ActivityThread(31488): ClassLoader.loadClass: The class loader returned by Thread.getContextClassLoader() may fail for processes that host multiple applications. You should explicitly specify a context class loader. For example: Thread.setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
02-15 13:12:33.151: D/AbsListView(31488): Get MotionRecognitionManager
02-15 13:12:34.012: D/dalvikvm(31488): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1344K, 15% free 14394K/16775K, paused 28ms+24ms, total 215ms
02-15 13:12:34.012: D/dalvikvm(31488): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 85ms
02-15 13:12:34.032: D/dalvikvm(31488): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 90ms
02-15 13:12:34.032: D/dalvikvm(31488): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 79ms
02-15 13:12:34.032: E/Google Maps Android API(31488): Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
02-15 13:12:34.042: E/Google Maps Android API(31488): In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
02-15 13:12:34.042: E/Google Maps Android API(31488): Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
02-15 13:12:34.042: E/Google Maps Android API(31488): Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
02-15 13:12:34.042: E/Google Maps Android API(31488):   API Key: My API Key
02-15 13:12:34.042: E/Google Maps Android API(31488):   Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): 
My Debug Certificate 
02-15 13:12:34.062: I/Google Maps Android API(31488): Failed to contact Google servers. Another attempt will be made when connectivity is established.
02-15 13:12:34.553: D/libEGL(31488): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
02-15 13:12:34.593: D/libEGL(31488): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
02-15 13:12:34.593: D/libEGL(31488): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
02-15 13:12:34.693: D/OpenGLRenderer(31488): Enabling debug mode 0
02-15 13:12:34.833: I/libblt_hw(31488): Library opened (handle = 0, fd = 47)
02-15 13:12:35.253: D/dalvikvm(31488): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 965K, 15% free 14586K/17159K, paused 202ms, total 205ms
02-15 13:12:39.347: D/dalvikvm(31488): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1651K, 16% free 14607K/17351K, paused 18ms+5ms, total 138ms
02-15 13:12:49.567: E/Google Maps Android API(31488): Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
02-15 13:12:49.707: D/dalvikvm(31488): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1715K, 17% free 14605K/17415K, paused 18ms+9ms, total 187ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mobile has lowe play version compared to the one you are using in program. I suggest you use a real device(update the play version of the device). If not a real device try using GenyMotion emulator.

Add this in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Your code should be as below with it:

```
    <permission android:name="ie.itsligo.medication.permission.MAPS_RECIEVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="ie.itsligo.medication.permission.MAPS_RECIEVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Paramedic"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
      <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value=""/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I added that to the AndroidManifest.xml this time logcat gives me a new error - AndroidRuntime(11386)

Comment: Post the logcat. Update the logs with the current one

Comment: Your layout file name mentioned here is activity.xml whereas in setContentView its activity_paramedic. It has to be  `setContentView(R.layout.activity);`

Comment: sorry my layout file name is activity_paramedic.xml it was a typo on my behalf. I will edit now and update the log because a new error has occurred

Comment: Your mobile has lowe play version compared to the one you are using in program. I suggest you use a real device(update the play version of the device). If not a real device try using GenyMotion emulator.

Comment: Tried both ways but still errors. Updated log file posted.

Comment: You haven't fix the play services version issue...your device supports 6587000 whereas your app requires version 6599034. Try updating the play version of your device or use old play services version in your app(not recommended).

Comment: Also add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>` in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: The application now runs but the map is not displaying in the fragment. Its says it cant access the API. I followed this tutorial https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start I have updated the LogCat.

Comment: I have fixed the problem, I was not using the full package name when creating the API Key. Thanks for your help.